# Working with time of integer format using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Could anyone support me to query with SQL Server 2012?

I have an entity for recording the time from daily booking system:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBooking
(
    Id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    stationID varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    roomId varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    Leader varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Title nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    meeting_Date int NOT NULL,
    meeting_time int NOT NULL,
    end_time int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT tblBooking_pk PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

I tried to record the date and time in integer format with yyyyMMdd & H24:m formats

I want to book a room by empty slot and avoid these cases

**Case 1**:

- Queue 1: booked at 08:00 - 11:00    ->   status is success
- Queue 2: will book at 09:00 - 10:00 -> status is not success or
- Queue 2: will book at 08:00 - 11:00  -> status is not success (duplicate)

**Case 2**:

- Queue 1: booked at 09:00 - 10:30 -> status is success
- Queue 2: will book at 08:00 - 09:30 -> status is not success or
- Queue 2: will book at 09:30 - 11:00 -> status is not success

As of the above cases I have not enough idea to verify coming transaction.

I tried to use `>/<` operators or BETWEEN but it's will have issue coming to case #1

This is my effort so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblBooking a 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND a.roomId = 'IT234'
  AND a.meeting_date = 20220215
  AND a.meeting_time > 900 AND a.end_time < 1000

  /* AND ((a.meeting_time > 900 OR a.meeting_time < 1000)
        OR  (a.end_time > 900 Or a.end_time < 1000)) */
```

Could anyone help to improve my query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why use `integer` and not `date` and `time` data type ?

Comment: Thank you Squirrel, because the system was design from requirement and if we change in this case will effect to many systems

Comment: in your query you have `meeting_time` and `end_time ` but these are not listed in your schema

Comment: Sorry I miss copy the column name, I edit it

Comment: I miss update the script. Now is okay.